# Java get Source code from Website

Tags: java, html, export

This code is in a class and it gets the source code from a website. I would like get the code and print it out in a jTextArea that is in another class, but i have no idea how i can do that. how can i export this source code in another class?

```
public static void Connect() throws Exception{

    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
    URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();


    spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
    String strLine = "";

    while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){

        System.out.println(strLine);
    }

}
```

in the other class I have a button with this code:

```
    try{
        Connect();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You can just copy paste the code anywhere you want. If you have a good idea the imports will be added automatically. Instead of the println you will have to set the text of the jTextArea then.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the html for the page and put it into a `JTextArea`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second class, you would call

```
try{
    ClassA.Connect();
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Where ClassA is the name of the class where public static void Connect() is defined. Note that, by convention, the method name should begin with a lower case, so it should be public static void connect().